# SP2013: Calculated column returns 0 instead of "" when list items change

Tags: lookup-column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I've got a simple list with 3 columns; Employee Name, Status, and a calculated field. Status column is a dropdown choice between "Active" & "Inactive"

Calc field formula is: `=IF(Status="Active",[Employee Name],"")`

When I first setup the calc field, it works perfectly. It shows as blank when Status is set to "inactive". However, if I then edit a Status from Active to Inactive, the calc field for that item shows a 0 instead of a blank/nothing.

If i go in and simply look at the calc field config, and hit OK without changing anything, all items that had a 0 now show a blank/nothing like they should. The calc field is set to "Single line of text".

How do I make the calc field show "" even after an item has been edited?

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXT([text_column], "")
```

Comment: one tip regarding this answer: if you are using non-English regional settings use ; instead of ,